# python 3.5 pandas read excel and convert to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with a data as shown below:

```
 Col_Title1 | Col_Title2 | Col_Title3 | Label
 Row11      | Row12      | Row13      | 1
 Row21      | Row22      | Row23      | 2
 Row31      | Row32      | Row33      | 3
```

Using pandas, I read this excel file like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(FOLDER_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION + '1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Now, I wish to output the following list using the `df` :

```
1. [[Row11, Row12, Row13], [Row21, Row22, Row23], [Row31, Row32, Row33]]

2. [1,2,3]
```

I don't know the efficient way or a good technique to attain those type of list outputs.

P.S. I'm a newbie in programming & sorry for asking this type of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need remove `Label` column, convert to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then to `list`:

```
a = df.drop('Label', 1).values.tolist()
print (a)
[['Row11', 'Row12', 'Row13'], ['Row21', 'Row22', 'Row23'], ['Row31', 'Row32', 'Row33']]
```

---

```
b = df['Label'].values.tolist()
print (b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use slicing, assuming you know the order of your columns in advance.

```
df_values = df.values

# [['Row11' 'Row12' 'Row13' 1]
#  ['Row21' 'Row22' 'Row23' 2]
#  ['Row31' 'Row32' 'Row33' 3]]
```

Then slice as appropriate:

```
df_values[:, :-1].tolist()

# [['Row11', 'Row12', 'Row13'],
#  ['Row21', 'Row22', 'Row23'],
#  ['Row31', 'Row32', 'Row33']]

df_values[:, -1].tolist()

# [1, 2, 3]
```